# The memory consistency model CUDA 4.0 and global memory?

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, cuda, cpu-architecture

Update: The `while()` condition below gets optimized out by the compiler, so both threads just skip the condition and enter the C.S. even with `-O0` flag. Does anyone know why the compiler is doing this? By the way, declaring the global variables `volatile` causes the program to hang for some odd reason...

I read the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) but I'm still a bit unclear on how CUDA handles **memory consistency** with respect to global memory. (This is different from the memory hierarchy) Basically, I am running tests trying to break **sequential consistency**. The algorithm I am using is *Peterson's algorithm for mutual exclusion between two threads* inside the kernel function:

```
flag[threadIdx.x] = 1; // both these are global
turn = 1-threadIdx.x;

while(flag[1-threadIdx.x] == 1 && turn == (1- threadIdx.x));
shared_gloabl_variable_x ++;

flag[threadIdx.x] = 0;
```

This is fairly straightforward. Each thread asks for the critical section by setting its flag to one and by being nice by giving the turn to the other thread. At the evaluation of the `while()`, if the other thread did not set its flag, the requesting thread can then enter the critical section safely. **Now a subtle problem with this approach is that if the compiler re-orders the writes so that the write to `turn` executes before the write to `flag`.** If this happens both threads will end up in the C.S. at the same time. This fairly easy to prove with normal Pthreads, since most processors don't implement sequential consistency. **But what about GPUs**?

Both of these threads will be in the same warp. And they will execute their statements in lock-step mode. But when they reach the `turn` variable they are writing to the same variable so the intra-warp execution becomes serialized (doesn't matter what the order is). Now at this point, does the thread that wins proceed onto the while condition, or does it wait for the other thread to finish its write, so that both can then evaluate the `while()` at the same time? The paths again will diverge at the `while()`, because only one of them will win while the other waits.

After running the code, I am getting it to consistently break SC. The value I read is ALWAYS 1, which means that both threads somehow are entering the C.S. every single time. How is this possible (GPUs execute instructions in order)? (Note: I have compiled it with `-O0`, so no compiler optimization, and hence no use of `volatile`).

Comment: When the two threads reach the `turn = 1-threadIdx.x;` statement, they do not diverge. Instead, one of the threads gets to perform its write. Which one, is undefined. The output from the other thread is lost. This is true for both global and shared memory writes.

Comment: "The value I read is ALWAYS 1". You mean `shared_gloabl_variable_x`?

Comment: "Now a subtle problem with this approach is if the compiler re-orders the writes so the write to turn executes before the write to flag." Are you referring to swapping the first two lines? If so, why would that matter?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, I mean the first two lines. In the general pthreads case, say T0 re-orders turn, context-switch to T1, T1 continues until the while() which it will clear and in the process sets turn to T0. Now context switch back to T0 and updates the flag variable and continues to the while(). Since turn is set back to 0 in T1 T0 will also enter the C.S. Now both threads are in the C.S. GPU's should not have this happening since they are supposed to execute in-order. Please read my update above in the problem description.

Comment: Did you find a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: since you have only two threads and `1-threadIdx.x` works, then you must be using thread IDs 0 and 1.  Threads 0 and 1 will always be part of the same warp on all current NVIDIA GPUs.  Warps execute instructions SIMD fashion, with a thread execution mask for divergent conditions.  Your while loop is a divergent condition.

- When `turn` and `flags` *are not* `volatile`, the compiler probably reorders the instructions and you see the behavior of both threads entering the C.S.
- When `turn` and `flags` *are* `volatile`, you see a hang. The reason is that one of the threads will succeed at writing turn, so `turn` will be either 0 or 1.  Let's assume `turn==0`: If the hardware chooses to execute thread 0's part of the divergent branch, then all is OK.  But if it chooses to execute thread 1's part of the divergent branch, then it will spin on the while loop and thread 0 will never get its turn, hence the hang.

You can probably avoid the hang by ensuring that your two threads are in different warps, but I think that the warps must be concurrently resident on the SM so that instructions can issue from both and progress can be made.  (Might work with concurrent warps on different SMs, since this is global memory; but that might require __threadfence() and not just __threadfence_block().)

In general this is a great example of why code like this is unsafe on GPUs and should not be used.  I realize though that this is just an investigative experiment.  In general CUDA GPUs do not—as you mention most processors do not—implement sequential consistency.

**Original Answer**

1. the variables `turn` and `flag` need to be `volatile`, otherwise the load of `flag` will not be repeated and the condition `turn == 1-threadIdx.X` will not be re-evaluated but instead will be taken as `true`.
2. There should be a `__threadfence_block()` between the store to `flag` and store to `turn` to get the right ordering.
3. There should be a `__threadfence_block()` before the shared variable increment (which should also be declared `volatile`).  You may also want a `__syncthreads()` or at least `__threadfence_block()` after the increment to ensure it is visible to other threads.

I have a hunch that even after making these fixes you may still run into trouble, though. Let us know how it goes.

BTW, you have a syntax error in this line, so it's clear this isn't exactly your real code:

```
while(flag[1-threadIdx.x] == 1 and turn==[1- threadIdx.x]);
```

Comment: Hi Harrism: You are missing the point of this question. I can easily make this problem work correctly by doing something simple as the atomic add instruction. The point of this exercise is to understand why sequential consistency is being broken despite the use of a mutual exclusion algorithm without locks. This can only happen with processor/compiler re-ordering of instructions. I know the gpu's are relaxed consistency but the processor's don't re-order instructions. So the question is how can this still be failing... By the way, using volatile causes the program to hang, I don't know why...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I hope the edits I just made provide some insight.  Note that even if the processors issue instructions in order, that is not the same as sequential *memory* consistency.  The memory system (caches, store buffers, etc.) may cause memory updates to appear to be reordered. Sequential consistency has a very large performance cost.

Comment: That making those variables volitile will hang is no longer true with volta generation nvidia gpu's - independent sub-warp progress can be made, at the cost of the inherent parallelism - see http://www.nvidia.com/content/gated-pdfs/Volta-Architecture-Whitepaper-v1.1.pdf p.26

Comment: That's true. However you definitely need the variables to be `volatile` for this to work on Volta.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of extra memory barriers such as __threadfence(), sequential consistency of global memory is enforced only within a given thread.

Comment: So you are saying that global memory is cached? I didn't read anywhere in the docs that global memory gets cached. Even if its cached, all threads in a warp share the same L1 cache right? So they would still see the changes.

Comment: On CUDA hardware that includes caches (Fermi and beyond), writes to global memory are cached.

Comment: Ok.But the threads on a same SM share the L1 cache so they will see the updates. Also, I edited the original post with an update. You have any ideas as to why the while() condition isn't evaluated?